# Java GUI Help (JFrame, JButton, etc)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

Ok so im new to programming GUIs in Java and I need some help on how to add buttons and Labels. I went around looking at an example and I figured it this was how it worked to basically add a button:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class GUI_Tests extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        private JButton button;
        button = new JButton("pls work");
        add(button);

    }

}
```

Well that didnt work at all... Can someone show me how its done and give me some pointers?

Comment: Generally speaking, extending directly from `JFrame` is normally discouraged as you are not adding anything to the class per say.  Instead, start with something like a `JPanel`.  This can then be added to whatever top level container (or any other container) you want...

Answer (score 3):

- You should note that a JFrame has a default BorderLayout which, if not specified, will add a component to a `BorderLayout.CENTER` position.
- When adding components to `JFrame`, if a different Layout is not specified, then you want to set a component's position, like `add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`
- Also you should use a constructor. Something like this

  ```
  public class GUI_Tests extends JFrame {
      public GUI_Tests(){
          JButton button = new JButton("Pls work");
          JLabel label = new JLabel("Pls work");
          add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      }
  }
  ```
- Also you need to remember to set the frame visible.

A simple running program would be something like this

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI_Tests extends JFrame {

    public GUI_Tests() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Pls work");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Pls work");
        add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new GUI_Tests();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

- The `main` method may look somewhat crazy to you, but all it is doing is causing the program to run on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). I won't go into this too much as you are still a beginner.
- What is going on in the `run` is that all I do is create an instance of me program, which `extends JFrame`. If I didn't extend `JFrame`, I would have to explicitly create a `JFrame` to run the program. All GUI programs need some top-level container to run.
- Also you can see in the constructor, that when I added the `button` and `label` I set a layout position

  ```
  add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  ```

  as I stated earlier, when using a `JFrame` without specifying a different layout, you should use position with the default `BorderLayout. Other possible positions are

  ```
  BorderLayout.EAST
  BorderLayout.WEST
  BorderLayout.CENTER
  BorderLayout.NORTH
  BorderLayout.SOUTH
  ```

  Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container]Laying Out Components Within a Container)
- Also, noticed I used `pack()`. What this does is make the frame the perfect with for the preferrsed sizes of the components. It is preferred to `pack()` rather then `setSize()` of a frame.
- `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` makes it so that when x out the frame, the program shuts down.
- `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` set the frame's location in the center of the screen
- `setVisible(true);` makes the frame visible. This should always be called to make the frame visible on start of the program.

Please have a look at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Can you explain the example a little, there are some really good points in there that aren't demonstrated in the other answers ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I'll get started. I want to make sure you fully understand everything :D

Comment: Also mention what `pack` does...this is so readily over looked, but oh so useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to add your `JButton` to a `JFrame`, but it seems to me that you haven't even created a `JFrame` yet. You should first create an instance of `GUI_Tests`, then use the `JFrame#add` method with your `JButton`. For example:

```
public class GUI_Tests extends JFrame {
    public GUI_Tests() {
        super("My first Swing frame!");

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create your GUI here
        this.add(new JButton("Click on me :)"));

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Actually, I wouldn't be mean to you, but I think you tried to go too fast: in my opinion, you should start by following some tutorial on how to deal with Swing :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your button to a `JFrame` The basic flow should look something like this:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUITests extends JFrame{

    public GUITests() {
        setTitle("Simple example");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        JButton button = new JButton("pls work");
        add(button);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUITests ex = new GUITests();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The GUITests class extends the `JFrame` class so you can call all the methods that are visible on the `JFrame` class. In the main method It's just some boiler plate code that calls your constructor for you so that you can see your basic example.

Check out the tutorials here: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/

Comment: NitPick - But you shouldn't really use `setSize` as it's possible for the content of the window to exceed the design size of the window on systems.  Better to use `pack` - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good point, was originally just firing from the hip, need to brush on up my swing best practices!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GUI_Tests extends JFrame {

    private JButton button;

    public GUI_Tests() {
        setTitle("Title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // so that the application properly closes when you click close
        button = new JButton("pls work");
        add(button);
        pack(); // resize the frame to its contents
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center the frame on the screen
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // properly start a swing application
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUI_Tests gui = new GUI_Tests();
                gui.setVisible(true); // set the frame visible 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

hope this helps you understand it a bit more. i didn't use any layouts in this code as its just a simple example, however, i highly recommend you to read on built-in layouts in swing and how to use them.
[Here's one good start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Apart from extending `JFrame`, this is a nice answer ;)  You might like to mention layout managers, as the OP might get a surprise when they try this ;)

Comment: thanks! i was just working on top of OP's code, and as for layout managers, i did leave a link to a oracle site where OP can read and learn about different layouts :)

Answer (score 0):

type

```
setVisible( true );
setSize( 500 , 500 );
```

and I think you'll see something. Also get rid of private in the statement `private JButton button` But you should really put your code in the constructor of the GUI_Tests:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI_Tests extends JFrame {
    public GUI_Tests() {
        JButton button = new JButton( "Hello World" );
        add( button );
        setVisible( true );
        setSize( 500 , 500 );
    }

    final public static void main( String[] args ) {
        GUI_Tests tests = new GUI_Tests();
    }
}
```

Check out the Java tutorial for more help, possibly here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html

Comment: NitPick - But you shouldn't really use `setSize` as it's possible for the content of the window to exceed the design size of the window on systems.  Better to use `pack`. You should also be making best-effort to start the UI from within the context of the EDT, as described in [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) - IMHO